# Mongo db returning empty results

Tags: node.js, mongodb

**My code**:

```
MongoClient.connect(gloabl_vars.db.mongo.url,function(err, db) {
        if(err) { throw err;    }
        var dbo=db.db("profilemanager");      
         var mquery={_id:'123454'}; 
 db.collection('userinfo').find(mquery,{'_id':0,'subscriptions':1}).toArray(function(err,result){
          if(err) throw err;
          console.log(result); 
        });
      });
      }
```

am able to get the result from `Robo3T mongo client` but same is returning null through `nodejs`.

```
Robo3T:
    db.getCollection('userinfo').find({_id:'66613'},{'_id':0,'subscriptions':1});
```

Comment: Are you sure you are searching on the correct database and/or server? That's the only possible variance you are not showing here. The drivers work fine for the other couple of million people out there using it without problem, so the only cause here is you are actually pointing at different places. Or "wrong values" since you are in fact issuing a different query to what you are dating workds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching a record by `{_id:'66613'}` in `Robo3T` but your sample is `{_id:'123454'}` in node.js. Also `projection` in node.js `find` is not in this way. Try below Snippet

```
MongoClient.connect(gloabl_vars.db.mongo.url,function(err, db) {
        if(err) { throw err;    }
        var dbo=db.db("profilemanager");      
        var mquery={_id:'66613'}; 
db.collection('userinfo').find(mquery).project({'_id':0,'subscriptions':1}).toArray(function(err,result){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(result); 
        });
    });
    }
```

Comment: Yes projection is wrong in my code. thanks for helping me in this.